# iterator (loop) on array starts at field 0 again after last field (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

This is about a simple logic comparing the header (first line) fields of a csv read by a BufferedReader (yellow, see screenshot below) to the fields of this given array:

```
static String[] HEADER_VALUE = {"Time", "Table Accel X", "Table Accel Y", "Table Accel Z", "Table Gyro X", "Table Gyro Y", "Table Gyro Z", "Table Temp", "Nozzle Accel X", "Nozzle Accel Y", "Nozzle Accel Z", "Nozzle Gyro X", "Nozzle Gyro Y", "Nozzle Gyro Z", "Nozzle Temp"};
```

[image: cvs file marked up in excel]

**this is my code:**

```
private void validateFieldCount(BufferedReader br) {
        
        String separator = ",";
        String line;
        Integer lineNumber = 0;
        try{
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
                String fields[] = line.split(separator);
                if (lineNumber.equals(1)){
                    for (int itemCount = 0; itemCount < 10; itemCount++)
                    try{                    
                        if (fields[itemCount].equals(HEADER_VALUE[itemCount])){ 
                            System.out.println(itemCount + " | " + "ok    " + " | " + fields[itemCount] + " | " + HEADER_VALUE[itemCount]);                     
                        }
                        else
                            System.out.println(itemCount + " | " + "not ok!" + " | " + fields[itemCount] + " | " + HEADER_VALUE[itemCount]);
                    
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("metaDataFile header check error");}
                    }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("sendorDataFile field error");
    }
}
```

**this is the output:**

```
0 | ok     | Time | Time
1 | ok     | Table Accel X | Table Accel X
2 | ok     | Table Accel Y | Table Accel Y
3 | ok     | Table Accel Z | Table Accel Z
4 | ok     | Table Gyro X | Table Gyro X
5 | ok     | Table Gyro Y | Table Gyro Y
6 | ok     | Table Gyro Z | Table Gyro Z
7 | ok     | Table Temp | Table Temp
8 | ok     | Nozzle Accel X | Nozzle Accel X
9 | ok     | Nozzle Accel Y | Nozzle Accel Y
10 | ok     | Nozzle Accel Z | Nozzle Accel Z
11 | ok     | Nozzle Gyro X | Nozzle Gyro X
12 | ok     | Nozzle Gyro Y | Nozzle Gyro Y
13 | ok     | Nozzle Gyro Z | Nozzle Gyro Z
14 | ok     | Nozzle Temp | Nozzle Temp
0 | not ok! | 03816794 | Time
1 | not ok! | 26.339623206637313 | Table Accel X
2021-03-23 21:16:12.898 ERROR 5232 ---[ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     [id: 0x93cabbee, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:51837] Error was received while reading the incoming data. The connection will be closed.
```

**the question is:** why does it start counting after field 14 from 0 again (and puts values from line 16 into `fields[]` --> see red highlighted values on the csv picture)?
Then it throws the runtime error in last line of the output.

Also when I replace `HEADER_VALUE.length` by e.g. `10` it will give an output of 12 lines with exactly the last 2 "not ok!" lines + runtime error.

Many thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Your code does not output anything. Because `lineNumber` never becomes`1`.

Comment: indeed I accidentially deleted line ```lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;``` by deleting the comments before posting; just edited the code, sorry

Comment: Rather than some arbitrary end bound (10), you should use the length of the array you are traversing: over:
`for (int itemCount = 0; itemCount < fields.length && itemCount < HEADER_VALUE.length; itemCount++) { ... }` Optionally you could also check to see if the length of `fields` mismatches `HEADER_VALUE` beforehand, then only check for the one array's bounds

Answer (score 0):

Curly brackets imbalance?
The closing-bracket before the outer catch corresponds to the opening-braket after the while statement and not with the opening-braket after the outer try.

I couldn't investigate this further for obvious reasons. I hope this is the solution for you.

Comment: I just edited the missing curly bracked which was further below in my original code; I'll write a compilable program that isolated this and edit the request; maybe I'll get the solution myself